# How do I upload multiple files to NodeJS using Golang?

Tags: node.js, go, multipartform-data, multer

I'm trying to upload few files to a NodeJS server using Golang.
I've managed to send one file at a time, one after another. Since this is a bad practice, I want to know how to send multiple files within one POST request.

This is the client:

```
func uploadFiles() {
    for _, file := range filesToSend {
        requestBody := &bytes.Buffer{}

        fileWriter := multipart.NewWriter(requestBody)

        part, _ := fileWriter.CreateFormFile("file", file)

        currentFile, _ := os.Open(file)
        defer currentFile.Close()

        io.Copy(part, currentFile)

        fileWriter.Close()

        r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:6969/uploadData", requestBody)
        r.Header.Add("Content-Type", fileWriter.FormDataContentType())
        client := &http.Client{}

        defer client.Do(r)
    }
}
```

This is the NodeJS handling (using multer):

```
app.post('/uploadData', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.socket.remoteAddress.replace(/:/g, '-');
    const file = req.file;

    fs.readFile(file.path, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error');
            return;
        }

        if (!fs.existsSync(__dirname + `\\data\\${ip}`))
            fs.mkdirSync(__dirname + `\\data\\${ip}`);

        fs.writeFile(__dirname + `\\data\\${ip}\\${file.originalname}`, data, (err) => {
            if (err) 
                console.log(err);

            fs.unlinkSync(file.path);

            res.sendStatus(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you facing issues, client side code or on nodejs?

Comment: [Create a multipart file writer](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#NewWriter). For each file, [create a part](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Writer.CreateFormFile) and copy the file to the part.  [Close](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Writer.Close) the file writer.  Post the file writer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set a multiple input file in frontend then send it with one post.
For multer part you need to change :

```
app.post('/uploadData', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
//to this
app.post('/uploadData', upload.array('file'), (req, res) => {
```